# Excel VBA macro for a complicated Copy Function

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA though I have done some coding in other languages so I understand some general concepts. I need to write a macro for excel that copies some data from a workbook in a single column that is non-contiguous to a single column in a new workbook that is contiguous. The difficult part is that I need the data being copied to be selected by user prompt, and the magnitude of each selection varies. Finally, the new workbook with a single column would be saved as a tab separated text file. This is what I had in mind, in sort of general coding language.

I will use *italics* to distinguish variables, "quotes" to distinguish values, and **bold** to distinguish coding key words. I am assuming the code would be run from the new empty workbook.

CODE: 
 
    %%% Initialize Variables. 
    *MoreCells* = "1" %%%boolean yes/no prompt later 
    *SelectedCells* = "range selected at prompt later" 
    *SelectedCellsMagnitude* = "# of cells in selectedcells" 
    *DestinationStartCell* = "A1" %%%cell to start at for range being copied to 
 
    Open workbook "workbook to be copied from.xlsx" 
 
    **While** *morecells* = "1" 
         prompt user to select range 
         set "selected range" = *selectedcells* 
         set "magnitude of *selectedcells*" = *selectedcellsmagnitude* 
         copy *selectedcells* to new workbook starting at cell *destinationstartcell* 
         set *destinationstartcell* = *destinationstartcell* + *selectedcellsmagnitude* 
         prompt user "Are there more cells to copy?" 
         **if** "yes" set *morecells* = "1" 
         **else** set *morecells* = "0" 
 
    save new workbook as tab separated value text file named "newworkbookname.txt" at destination "\new\workbook\destination"

:END CODE

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Or, for that matter, insight to whether this is possible in VBA with excel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's definitely possible. If you're needing additional input from the user then you'll have to incorporate a VBA userform as well. So the code would basically call the userform, get the data from it when its closed, then continue alone its merry way. I am, however, confused by what you mean when you say "Magnitude"

Comment: That makes sense I think.  By magnitude I mean simply the number of cells selected.  The idea being that this information allows the loop to start at the correct cell when it goes to copy the next selection into the new workbook (so it doesn't write over the previously copied cells).

Answer (score 0):

Change the workbook and sheet values to the applicable workbook and sheets

```
Sub usermove()
Dim c, Rng1 As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = 1

'ask for input
userselect:
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set Rng1 = Application.InputBox("Please Select Cells", Type:=8)

'loop
For Each c In Rng1.Cells

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

  Cells(i, 1).Value = c.Value

    i = i + 1
    Next

'Prompt for more input
continue = MsgBox("Are there more cells to select?", vbYesNo)
If continue = vbYes Then GoTo userselect

'then save

    ChDir "path"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="path\Book1.txt", FileFormat _
        :=xlText, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Raystafarian!  This looks great, I will test it out at work tomorrow and let you know if I run into any issues, but with my limited VBA understanding it seems to make sense, I think it will do the trick.

Comment: I actually wanted to copy from a different workbook so I worked out how to do that in a way that seems to be working, but in general your code works great, thanks again!  Here are the modifications I made: apparently my code is too long to fit in a comment, :-/